# MapDB file types

Tags: mapdb

I have a problem with `mapDB version 1.0.6`. When i create a database i end up with two files with the same name but with different file types.

One is for example `IRTree` with file type `FILE` and the other is `IRTree` with file type `.p`
Having said that, whenever i try to read my database providing a filename IRTree i end up with an exception:

`NullPointerException with the command DBMaker.newFileDB(new File(filename)).readOnly().make(); or an IOException: storage header is invalid`.

Can anyone explain to me what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

MapDB uses two files. .P file is used to store data. Always open file without extension, otherwise it will try to open incorrect file.